# Microsoft Access OleDb .NET - Make a second query using the result of the first

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ms-access-2010, oledb

I have a MS Access 2010 database (.accdb) that I access and query via `System.Data.OleDb` in .NET (specifically C#), with `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.

For simplifying a bigger context, this database has two tables related one to many:

```
TB_PROJECT                 TB_SUBPROJECT
    PRJ_ID __________         SUBPRJ_ID
    PRJ_FIELD1       \_______ FOREIGN_PRJ_ID
    ....                      SUB_FIELD1
                              ....
                              OTHER_RELATIONS -------> some query condition that 
                                                       uses lots of inner joins
```

And I'm creating C# objects for each of the records in **both of** these tables satisfying a condition based on the `OTHER_RELATIONS`. And for querying the TB_PROJECT table, I need a join with TB_SUBPROJECT.

How can I create in C# a query for TB_PROJECT that uses the result of a previous query in TB_SUBPROJECT (and yet use this intermediate result for creating my C# objects)?

I can create queries with `OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()` for those items using the proper joins and necessary conditions, no problem, but I can only think of these two options:

- I can join everything and have a `SELECT TB_PROJECT.*, TB_SUBPROJECT.* FROM`result with multiple repeated projects (and treat the repeated projects in C#)
- Or I can make two separate queries for each table, the second using `SELECT DISTINCT TB_PROJECT.* FROM`. In this case I'd be wasting processing by making the same query for TB_SUBPROJECT twice. (I need the results of the intermediary query to create items in C#).

Comment: Not sure, if I understand your problem correctly. Sample data may help. Sounds like a `SELECT * FROM TB_PROJECT WHERE PRJ_ID IN ( SELECT DISTINCT FOREIGN_PRJ_ID WHERE OTHER_RELATIONS = ...)`, which is quite efficient. Or, if the objects were loaded (and there are not too many of them), just `IN ( 1, 2, 3, ... )`, so just append your already loaded IDs.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Gene, but with this, I'll have to perform the entire "OTHER_RELATIONS" query twice, one to get the SubProject list, and another to get the Project list.